# An Entropy Identity for Hidden Markov Models

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, information-theory, entropy

Let $\{X_i\}$ be a Stationary Markov chain, $\mathcal{X} = \text{range} X_i$ and let $\phi: \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}$ be a function that gives rise to another stochastic process $\{Y_i\}$, where $Y_i = \phi(X_i)$. I want to prove that

\begin{equation*}
H(Y_n | Y_{n-1},\dots,Y_1, X_1) = H(Y_n | Y_{n-1},\dots, Y_1, X_1, \color{red}{X_0, \dots , X_{-k}}),
\end{equation*}

where $k$ is an *arbitrary* integer.

I do not have any intuition or reason about why this should be true! Can you provide some? Also, I do not know where to start for proving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just conditional independence: for any $n$, given $X_1, X_2^n$ is independent of $X_{-k}^0$ due to the Markov structure. But $Y_1^n = f(X_1^n)$, so this is also independent of $X_{-k}^0$ given $X_1$, i.e., $$ H(Y_1^n|X_1, X_{-k}^0) = H(Y_1^n|X_1).$$ But then

\begin{align*}
H(Y_n|Y_1^{n-1},X_1) &= H(Y_1^n|X_1) - H(Y_1^{n-1}|X_1) \\ 
&= H(Y_1^n|X_1, X_{-k}^0) - H(Y_1^{n-1}|X_1,X_{-k}^0) \\ 
&= H( Y_n|Y_1^{n-1}, X_1, X_{-k}^0).
\end{align*}